# How to "embed" a front-end IDE in JS

Tags: javascript

Are there any libraries for creating a **front-end** **IDE** for JS? Just the animation but with functionalities like multiple tabs.

Great example:
[GitHub Copilot](https://github.com/features/copilot)
[image]

Comment: If you want tabs, you will need a tab manager. Many modern frameworks include this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple tab manager that allows you to switch between tabs.

You need to break this component into two sub-components:

1. The actual tabs you can click
2. The tab panel that is active

```js
const cursorPositionEnd = (textarea) => {
  textarea.focus();
  textarea.selectionStart = textarea.value.length;
};

const handleTabChange = (tab) => {
  const tabManager = tab.closest('.tab-manager');
  const index = [...tabManager.children].indexOf(tab);
  const tabWrapper = tabManager.closest('.tab-wrapper');
  const tabView = tabWrapper.querySelector('.tab-view');
  const tabPanel = tabView.querySelector(`.tab-panel:nth-child(${index + 1})`);

  if (!tab.classList.contains('.tab-active')) {
    tabManager.querySelectorAll('.tab.tab-active').forEach(activeTab => {
      activeTab.classList.remove('tab-active');
    });
    tab.classList.add('tab-active');
    tabView.querySelectorAll('.tab-panel.tab-panel-active').forEach(activeTabPanel => {
      activeTabPanel.classList.remove('tab-panel-active');
    });
    tabPanel.classList.add('tab-panel-active');
    cursorPositionEnd(tabPanel.querySelector('textarea'));
  }
}

const handleTabManagerChange = (e) => {
  const maybeTab = e.target.closest('.tab');
  if (maybeTab) handleTabChange(maybeTab);
}

document.querySelector('.tab-manager')
  .addEventListener('click', handleTabManagerChange);

cursorPositionEnd(document.querySelector('.tab-panel-active > textarea'));
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --editor-background-active: #24292F;
  --editor-background-inactive: #161B22;
  --editor-text-active: #FFFFFF;
  --editor-text-inactive: #8B949E;
  --editor-border-active: #30363d;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background: #242236;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.title-bar {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tab-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background: var(--editor-background-inactive);
  border: thin solid var(--editor-border-active);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.tab-manager {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0 0.5rem;
}

.tab {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--editor-text-inactive);
  font-size: smaller;
  border: thin solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.tab.tab-active {
  background: var(--editor-background-active);
  color: var(--editor-text-active);
  border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-top: thin solid var(--editor-border-active);
  border-left: thin solid var(--editor-border-active);
  border-right: thin solid var(--editor-border-active);
}

.tab > i {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}

.tab-view {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.tab-panel {
  position: absolute;
  background: var(--editor-background-active);
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.tab-panel.tab-panel-active {
  display: flex;
}

.tab-panel > textarea {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: var(--editor-text-active);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  resize: none;
  font-family: Inconsolata;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata
&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title-bar">Tabbed Editor</div>
  <div class="tab-wrapper">
    <div class="tab-manager">
      <div class="tab tab-active"><i class="fa-brands fa-js"></i> file-1.js</div>
      <div class="tab"><i class="fa-brands fa-js"></i> file-2.js</div>
      <div class="tab"><i class="fa-brands fa-js"></i> file-3.js</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-view">
      <div class="tab-panel tab-panel-active">
        <textarea>#!/usr/bin/env ts-node

import { fetch } from "fetch-h2";

async function </textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-panel">
        <textarea>This is the content of file 2.</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-panel">
        <textarea>This is the content of file 3.</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```